# Cannot perform Construct on a detached ArrayBuffer tfjs-backend-wasm with coco-ssd

Tags: tensorflow, webassembly, tensorflow.js

Trying to use https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-backend-wasm using direct script tags tried the dome core for mobilenet...working fine but trying    tf.setBackend('wasm') for coco-ssd throws error [][1]

```
Slice.ts:72 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 
Construct on a detached ArrayBuffer
at Float32Array.subarray (<anonymous>)
at slice (Slice.ts:72)
at Object.unpack [as kernelFunc] (ZerosLike.ts:23)
at p (engine.js:581)
at engine.js:639
at e.t.scopedRun (engine.js:444)
at e.t.runKernelFunc (engine.js:636)
at unstack_ (unstack.js:57)
at unstack__op (operation.js:51)
at e.t.scatter (tensor_array.js:265)
```

below are the script tags included

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"> </script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tf-backend-wasm.js"></script>
<script>
```